# Webkit Background Attachment Fixed bug

Tags: background, webkit, fixed, css-animations, animate.css

I use parallax effect. In firefox works ok, but in Chrome, Safari, Opera bg dissapear (webkit). I use too animate.css, so when i remove this styles, all works ok. I read a lot on stackoverflow about this situation, I tried with Backface-visbility.

URL with project: http://margar.edl.pl/

Comment: You need to provide code in order for us to help you.

Comment: Which background are you talking about?

Comment: Chrome/Opera all backgrounds without in home. In webkit white place (there are content too, but white color). I've read that this bug. I would skip this problem, but on my another page [link](http://inesta-wordpress.studio-themes.com) works. And I made almost the same.

Comment: I'm betting it's because of the transforms on the parent elements, `body` and `html`, but I cannot test *anything* because your site isn't letting me change the CSS. You should provide relevant code *in the question itself* so we can help you more

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yFgy8/ maybe look this. This is not 100% of my situation, but you can see that there is a problem with the fixed. I tried with webkit Backface, ztrasnlate, the problem still was.

Comment: [It seems to work fine](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/yFgy8/1/) once jQuery is added. Also, you still provide too much code. You need to learn how to localize your problem to get good, quick responses from SO

Comment: Just the problem appeared suddenly and have it only on the page. I can not share the package with the site. However, look for another solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found a solution. I removed the relative position of the container with parallax effect. I do not know why it just worked.